# Use two Kafka producer factories in KafkaEmbedded unit test

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use KafkaEmbedded for my consumer unit tests, where I have two create two different producers with two different serialisers, and two different topics:

```java
// first producer factory
Map<String, Object> firstProducerProperties = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaEmbedded);
firstProducerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
firstProducerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
firstProducerProperties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, properties.getKafka().getSchemaRegistryUrl());

ProducerFactory<String, TicketChange> firstProducerFactory =
    new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(firstProducerProperties);

firstTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(firstProducerFactory);
firstTemplate.setDefaultTopic("topic-one");

...

 // second producer factory
Map<String, Object> secondProducerProperties = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaEmbedded);
secondProducerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
secondProducerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

ProducerFactory<String, TicketChange> secondProducerFactory =
    new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(secondProducerProperties);

secondTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(secondProducerFactory);
secondTemplate.setDefaultTopic("topic-two")
```

Then, as described [here](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-embedded-unit-test-example.html), I assign partitions to producers:

```java
for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
    .getListenerContainers()) {

  ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer,
      kafkaEmbedded.getPartitionsPerTopic() * 2);
}
```

The last line the number of partitions is multiplied by the number of topics. If I run the tests I get the following error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :2
Actual   :1
 <Click to see difference>


  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(ContainerTestUtils.java:74)
  at com.ks.cfc.service.kafka.KafkaEmbeddedBase.setUp(KafkaEmbeddedBase.java:92)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

It is like I have to add somehow additional listeners? message handlers for each of the producers?

Comment: You need to show your `@KafkaListener` (s).

Comment: You should be sure that your `@KafkaListener` is subscribed to both mentioned topics.

Comment: I understand I should have a listener container for each of the factories, right?, how can I register those for the producers? (i.e. in my first snippet) I mean, I don't see how to use the @KafkaListener annotation there?... It is written in the docs "The link to the message listener container is acquired by auto-wiring the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry which manages the lifecycle of the listener containers that are not created manually" - how to manually create them?